# Can I connect Trillian to Xbox Live / Steam / Battle.net chat?

Tags: xmpp, trillian

I don't know too much about XMPP or the extent of Trillian Plugins, but it sure would be neat to see notifications when friends are playing...

Comment: You cannot connect any external client to Battle.net and/or Steam.  Just have your XBox Live Friends enable Microsoft Messenger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This guy](http://benhollis.net/software/xblist/) is half way there.
He's created a PC Chat client for Xbox Live.

Hopefully he opens his code for someone to create it as a plugin.